# Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /home/central1/public_html/wp-content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

How to remove:- **Fatal error**:

> Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in
>   the script in
>   /home/central1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wcp-openweather/classes/Settings.class.php
>   on line 2

Comment: this is the second line in code: <?php namespace Webcodin\WCPOpenWeather\Plugin;

use Webcodin\WCPOpenWeather\Core\Agp_SettingsAbstract;

class Settings extends Agp_SettingsAbstract {
    
    private $currentId;
    
    private $currentTag;
    
    private $currentTemplate;

Comment: Please help me to resolve it...Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this issue come because of space in php start tag of controller facing same issue just removed whitespace in

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

removing the space resolved my error.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Settings.class.php` write your `namespace` declaration at the top, I mean just after starting `<?php` tag. It would solved that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but i did not understand it. actually i am new in wordpress. Can you please describe in details

Comment: <?php namespace Webcodin\WCPOpenWeather\Plugin;

use Webcodin\WCPOpenWeather\Core\Agp_SettingsAbstract;

class Settings extends Agp_SettingsAbstract {
    
    private $currentId;
    
    private $currentTag;
    
    private $currentTemplate;

Comment: this is the second line on setting.class.php

Comment: In case you want to know more here you will find details. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php